# Nginx Block User-Agent "-"

Tags: nginx, http-headers, user-agent, access-control, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I'm getting some kind of access that is causing problems on my server:

```
172.68.28.210 - - [03/Jul/2016:13:41:06 -0300] " "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 166 "-" "-"
```

I would like to block even the $HTTP_USER_AGENT, made this attempt did not work.

```
if ($http_user_agent = "-") {
        return 403;
    }
```

Someone would know what's wrong?

Comment: The 502 means internal server error. Are you proxying the requests to something else? Could you please post your NGINX config as well?

Answer (score 2):

That is because the `$http_user_agent` variable may have different value depending on the context.

If the header is absent in the request, then [it'll present itself as `-` in your `access_log`](http://ngx.su/src/http/modules/ngx_http_log_module.c#ngx_http_log_variable), all the while still being just empty within your if-statement.

Thus, perhaps the following is what you want instead:

```
if ($http_user_agent = "") {
    return 403;
}
```

Comment: @Marcos, did this work for you?  If yes, please don't forget to accept and upvote.  thanks!