# Block User-agent have "-" "-"

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I was ddos with some IP have user agent `"-" "-"`
Example:

```
34.81.3x.x - - [01/Jun/2022:09:51:33 +0700] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "-"
34.81.3x.y - - [01/Jun/2022:09:51:33 +0700] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "-"
34.81.3x.z - - [01/Jun/2022:09:51:33 +0700] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "-"
34.81.3x.p - - [01/Jun/2022:09:51:33 +0700] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "-"
...
```

And i use code block user-agent:

```
    if ($http_user_agent ~ ("-" "-")) {
        return 403;
    }
```

But when i restart nginx, have error:
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

How to fix it, thanks

Comment: I think you're misreading your server logs, are you sure the `"-"` doesn't mean an empty-string or unspecified header, instead of a literal dash surrounded by literal double-quotes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx Block User-Agent "-"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172128/nginx-block-user-agent)